# Regex postive lookbehind only if after specific string

Tags: regex, powershell, email, expression

I'm trying to form a regex to find the "from" address for any forwarded emails. There may be multiple formats, so it needs to match this pattern [Ffrom:] [there may be more text here including spaces,",A-Z,a-z,<,[, and multiple words] and then an email address. Here's what I have so far:

`(?<=)[\w-]*@[\w-]*[.\w]*`

This finds any email addresses, but I need it to only find those following this pattern. `"From:" ["Possible Sender Name Here"] example-email1@test2.co.uk` The line will always start with "[Ff]rom:" and this will be implemented in Powershell if that matters.

Comment: You are not specifying condition for lookbehind. `(?<=)`  means zero width. It bound to find some of them.

Comment: does the email not have `<>`'s? around it i.e. `From: "Fooy McBar" <Fooy@bar.com>`

Comment: Even if it is having, this regex will return true only `'(?<=)[\w-]*@[\w-]*[.\w]*'`

Answer (score 0):

Usually headers are in the format `From: "Fooy McBar" <Fooy@bar.com>` which can be matched with:

```
-replace 'From:.*<(.+)>','$1'
```

Really the easiest way to match an email address at the end of a line is to just match everything after the last whitespace though:

```
-replace '^.*\s(.+)$','$1'
```

will match `Fooy@bar.com` in both:

```
From: "Fooy McBar" Fooy@bar.com
```

and

```
From: Fooy@bar.com
```

Comment: you could also use a match to grab only valid email addresses, [although that can sometimes be a problem](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)